# Proving a statement in linear algebra: having the intuition but lacking rigor

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional $K$-vector space and $f:V \to V$ a linear transformation such that $f^n=0,f^{n-1}\neq0$. Prove that there's a base $B$ of $V$ such that
>
> $$\big(|f|_B \big)_{ij}=\begin{cases} 1 \text{  if }i=j+1 \\0 \text{ 
>    otherwise}\end{cases}$$

**I've got the general idea of how to prove this, but I suck at manipulating subindexes.**

Constructively, we can show that $B$ exists. Let's pick $v \not\in \ker{f^{n-1}}$, which by hypothesis we can do.

Let's then define $B=\{b_1,\dots,b_n\}=\{v,f(v),f^2(v),\dots,f^{n-1}(v)\}$. If we can show that $B$ is an l.i. set, then we've shown that $B$ is a basis for $V$ (given that they have the same dimension). Let's suppose otherwise, i.e. there's some $a_i,0\leq i\leq n-1$ such that

$$a_0 v + a_1 f(v) + a_{n-1} f^{n-1} v = 0$$

If we keep the terms with nonzero $a_i$ on the left, except for the one with the highest $i$, we get something like $b= a_i f^i (v)$. If we apply $f$ $(n-i)$-times to both sides, we get $f^{n-i}(\dots)=0$. Applying this procedure recursively, we well find that $a_j f^j(v)=0$ for some $j<n, a_j \neq 0$, something that contradicts the original assumption.

Since $B$ is a basis, $|f|_B$ is defined. It's easy to see that each column $(f(b_i))_B$ has a $1$ in the $i+1$-th position and zeros everywhere else.

**How can I say this more formally? Alternatively, how can I get better at saying these kinds of things more formally?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $f^{n}=0$ implies $f^{n+1}=0, f^{n+2}=0$ , etc. Apply $f^{n-1}$ to $a_0v+a_1f(v)+...+a_{n-1}f^{n-1}v=0$ to see that $a_0=0$. So we have $a_1f(v)+...+a_{n-1}f^{n-1}v=0$. Now apply $f^{n-2}$ to get $a_1=0$ and so on.